# Receiving 404 status when trying to load local files with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

I am relatively new to using Node and am trying to make a simple HTML page that can get images, stylesheets, and scripts locally. Every time I try to load a local file, it returns a 404 status. I have tried multiple solutions from StackOverflow and other sources and still cannot get this to work.

Here is my code in app.js:

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);

var portNumber = 8085;

app.get('/', function(reg, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

http.listen(portNumber, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + portNumber);
});
```

I have a CSS file at public > stylesheets > style.css linked to my HTML document.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/stylesheets/style.css" />`

[image: The file structure of my project]

I get a 404 error in my browser's console. I also get a MIME error:
The resource from “http://localhost:8085/public/stylesheets/style.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

[image: MIME Type and 404 errors in the Firefox console]

Any local images I try to load also give a 404 error.

I have tried adding `app.use(express.static('public'));` to make the public folder the root to serve static content as shown in the [Express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html), but I still got 404 errors.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);

var portNumber = 8085;

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(reg, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

http.listen(portNumber, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + portNumber);
});
```

I am not sure what I am supposed to do. All I want is to be able to load local files in my HTML document. How do I get these files to be displayed publicly instead of giving a 404 error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the mime error is actually confusing - it's due to the browser not being able to find that file.

Remove the `/public` part of the path location as that is the folder so it's being served from:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/style.css" />
```

Same for all your other static files: `/assets/mypic.png` etc

Update your location for the static path as follows:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {index: false}));
```

Then, update sendFile to use and `absolute` path as follows:

```
return res.sendfile(path.resolve('./index.html'));
// or
return res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
```

Comment: When I did this, the terminal says “Reference Error: path is not defined”

Comment: add `const path = require('path');` at the top of the file so that you import the `path` object

Answer (score 0):

You should try using

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

That way express knows where to search for that `public` folder.